# Why does super class overriden method called?

Tags: oop, haxe, nme

I am overriding a method ini in a super class, but strangely the ini method in super class is still called although I am not calling it using super

Any idea? is this a problem in haxe 3? 
p.s: its an OpenFL project, targeting flash ..

```
class superClass{
 function ini():Void 
 {
   // this line should not be reached, but, it is reached .. !
 }
}

class subClass extends superClass{
 override function ini():Void 
 {
   // I Am not calling super ini here ..
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is an abstract of my code, where you can see my classes set:

```
class EComponent extends Sprite
{

}

class Component extends EComponent
{

    public function new(aBoard:Board) 
    {
        ini();
    }
    function ini():Void 
    {
    // I am checking this manually, 
    // because ini is called even though its BeziereWire instance!
        if (Std.is(this, BeziereWire))
        return;
    }

    function iniRotators():Void 
    {

    }
}

class BeziereWire extends Component
{
    override function ini():Void 
    {
        iniRotators();      
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something special about the ini() method? Is it called by reflection or something like that? You haven't shown the calling code, or a test case that shows that superClass.ini() is called, so... it's hard to help

Comment: I am calling ini normally from superClass constructor, for some subClasses I need to cut superClass ini method by overriding it and not calling it, I am not using reflection or anything .. would you please make a little test, would it work at your side?

Comment: Your edited code still does not compile... so you're obviously not showing us the full picture yet.  I fixed the mistakes, and added the traces and it runs as expected: http://try.haxe.org/#091bA

Comment: Thanks Jason, I've been very busy working on OpenFL based project, your support highly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, something wrong with your real code. I make a test project and all works fine.
This is a test Main.hx - https://gist.github.com/sergey-miryanov/6658172

And this is a screenshot:
[image: And this is a screenshot]

Comment: Please submit your minimal test project that show a problem. So we try  to test it.

Comment: @simo there are things you are still not showing us, even the code in your edit does not compile.  I made some edits to get it to compile and it all works as expected: http://try.haxe.org/#091bA